# Opening Google Maps application in minimized view via Intent

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

fellow community!

So we all know that we can open Google Maps application from our applications using the Intent. That's cool.

And we also know that we could minimize Google Maps (I don't really know if it is a feature of Android OS or the application itself) that it will display above other applications in a small window.

But can we request the Google Maps application to start in a minimized window from our app, so that user won't need to do any interactions to minimize the Google Maps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch Google Maps intent and after few seconds launch back your app using timer for example.

Otherwise there is no option to start Google Maps in background.

Also, here is some [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! Have you tried this approach? Maybe you can attach some code for a better example.